# How do I concisely write a || b where a and b are Optional values?

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, java-9, option-type

I'm happy with an answer in any language, but I ultimately want an answer in Java. (Java 8+ is fine. Not limited to Java 8. I've tried to fix the tags.)

If I have two `Optional<Integer>` values, how do I concisely compute the equivalent of `a || b`, meaning: `a`, if it's defined; otherwise `b`, if it's defined; otherwise `empty()`?

```
Optional<Integer> a = ...;
Optional<Integer> b = ...;
Optional<Integer> aOrB = a || b; // How to write this in Java 8+?
```

I know that I can write `a.orElse(12)`, but what if the default "value" is also `Optional`?

Evidently, in C#, the operator `??` does what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Optional<Integer> aOrB =  a.isPresent() ? a : b;
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution without `isPresent()`, but this seems like the best we can do.

Comment: To me this looks the cleanest when there are only two variables. But it looks messy when you have more than two, whereas the Java 9 `or` method allows chaining: `a.or(()->b).or(()->c).or(()->d)`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException that chain looks messy to me too, for more than 2  I'd write a dedicated method `<T> Option<T> or(Option<T>... options)`  to take care of that

Comment: @DodgyCodeException: `Stream.of(a, b, c, d).flatMap(Optional::stream).findFirst()`

Comment: @Holger That's a nice one, have borrowed this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912373/how-do-i-concisely-write-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-optional-values/46912515#46912515). Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

In [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) you can follow any of these :

✓ Simply chain it using the **[`or`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-)** as :-

```
Optional<Integer> a, b, c, d; // initialized
Optional<Integer> opOr = a.or(() -> b).or(() -> c).or(() -> d);
```

implementation documented as -

> If a value is present, returns an `Optional` describing the value,
>   otherwise returns an `Optional` produced by the supplying function.

---

✓  Alternatively as pointed out by [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912373/how-do-i-concisely-write-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-optional-values#comment80779752_46912634), use the **[`stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--)** as:-

```
Optional<Integer> opOr = Stream.of(a, b, c, d).flatMap(Optional::stream).findFirst();
```

implementation documented as -

> If a value is present, returns a sequential `Stream` containing only
>   that value, otherwise returns an empty `Stream`.

Comment: Question is tagged with `java-8`

Comment: How 8+? In tag description is `specific` for java8

Comment: @ByeBye look at the code in the question *// How to write this in Java 8+?*

Comment: Ok, so tag should be added

Comment: I've added the tag in question.

Answer (score 7):

In `java-8` we don't have any solution to easy chain `Optional` objects, but you can try with:

```
Stream.of(a, b)
    .filter(op -> op.isPresent())
    .map(op -> op.get())
    .findFirst();
```

In `java9` you can do:

```
Optional<Integer> result = a.or(() -> b);
```

Comment: Stream is ordered by default

Comment: I was thinking of a fold over isPresent() with a default value of empty(), but I couldn't quite articulate it.

Comment: @J.B.Rainsberger inspired by your thought of a fold, I thought of `Stream.of(a, b).reduce(Optional.empty(), (opt1,opt2)->opt1.or(()->opt2))`.

Comment: In Java 9, you can also simplify your first variant to `Stream.of(a, b).flatMap(Optional::stream) .findFirst()`, which makes it easy to extend to more optionals…

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do something like this.

```
a.orElse(b.orElse(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

In `java-8` if you want something close to the `Optional::stream` mechanic, you could do

```
Stream.of(a, b)
  .flatMap(x -> 
     x.map(Stream::of)
      .orElse(Stream.empty())
  )
  .findFirst()
```

Comment: Can use guava `Streams::stream` as an alternative to Java 9 `Optional::stream`