# Difference between java 9 OR and java 8 orElseGet

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, java-9

Java9 has added `.or` method to Optional. How it is different for existing `.orElseGet` ?

```
checkUserInMemory(userId).or(() -> checkUserInDB(userId));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Primarily the return type of both varies.***

#### [Optional.orElseGet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-)

- The call to `orElseGet` returns the object `T` itself.
- throws `NullPointerException` if ***no value is present and the supplying function is `null`***
- Use case: To fetch the value deterministically based on the supplied function.

#### [Optional.or](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-)

- The `Optional.or` returns an `Optional` describing the value, otherwise returns an `Optional` produced by the supplying function
- throws `NullPointerException` if the ***supplying function is `null`*** or if the ***supplying function produces a `null` result.***
- Use case: To chain a series of `Optional`s based on the result of the supplied function. Sample -
  [How do I concisely write a || b where a and b are Optional values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46912515/1746118)

Answer (score 8):

`Optional.orElse` will return an `Object`, whereas `Optional.or` will return another `Optional`.

Comment: this isn't wrong but it doesn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that `Optional::orElseGet` supplier returns `T` while `Optional::or` supplier returns `Optional<T>`, the other more important difference between the two is that newer (more awesome) `Optional::or` is **composable** (further explained in my LinkedIn post [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-optionals-awesome-dexter-legaspi/)) while `Optional::orElseGet` isn't.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.